# Want to/wanna Which one should I use?

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-choice

I want to ask a question.

So I have always been using:

> I want to…

But now I use:

> I wanna…

Which one is the one I should use?

Comment: "Wanna" is colloquial and quite ugly (especially in writing), so my advice is to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer - "I want to" is correct English in all circumstances, "I wanna" is a [non standard](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wanna) informal contraction not used in written English unless you are reporting what someone said. Another contraction you will hear in spoken English is "I wanter"